# FFMPEG compilation without non free and without gpl not working properly

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

I tried to compile ffmpeg for LGPL (without nonfree and with out gpl).

I used following commands while configuring as mentioned in many blogs

`configure --prefix=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build --bindir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/bin --libdir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/lib --shlibdir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/slib --incdir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/include --datadir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/data --mandir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/man --pkgconfigdir=/home/sarun/ffmpeg-build/FFmpeg-release-4.0/build/slib/pkgconfig --disable-static --enable-shared`

after compilation i could still see non free codecs and gpl elements as part of installed libraries
please help me whether i am missing anything, i want to create LGPL version for my work.

Comment: Which non free components do you see?

Comment: after compilation i could see h264 and as well some avfilters which is part of gpl

Comment: h264 what? h264 decoder is lgpl. Store the output of configure to a file and share that.

Comment: some of GPL components listing in my configure section are                                             
Enabled filters:     blackdetect    , libraries : swsresample

Comment: Both blackdetect and libswresample are LGPL.

Comment: Hi Sorry , but i referred this page https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/LICENSE.md                                           where its mentioned blackframe is GPL

Comment: blackframe is GPL but blackdetect is LGPL.

Comment: ok thanks i was confused , now its clear